# BlogOverflow just blocked me for less than 10 page views as "too many requests from this IP address"

Tags: bug, blog, blog-overflow, ip-ban

I realize nobody reads it so it's "unusual" but come on guys I didn't even click 20 links!

> [image]

Granted, I only went to click those links because I spotted a bug with text and image formatting, and wanted to confirm it was on every site's blog.

Seems like it's blocking me for a minute after every 10 links clicked within 1 minute. A bit harsh.

Comment: Thought it was over but no, it blocked me again. Guess I can't click on more than 5 or so within a minute.

Comment: Somebody really don't want people to browse those blogs anymore...